# ¿Por qué en debian - apache cualquier dominio .dev apunta a localhost?

Tags: codeigniter, apache, debian, codeigniter-4

Testeando CodeIgniter 4, estaba configurando un VirtualHost en apache como recomiendan en la documentación de CI4, he creado el VirtualHost de tal manera que el dominio `ci4.dev` apunte al directorio publico de CI4 lo cual funciona correctamente, sin embargo no he configurado ningun VirtualHost adicional pero si pongo algo como `example.dev`, `otro.dev`, y cualquier dominio `.dev` estos apuntan a `localhost`.

**¿Existe alguna característica o configuración de apache que genere esta situación, o qué puede generar todo eso?**

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Debian y Apache estás utilizando? ¿Al ejecutar `apachectl -S` te confirma que los host *.dev están configurados desde Apache? [¿Tienes algún servicio atendiendo el puerto de DNS (53)?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buscando información al respecto pude obtener la siguiente respuesta:

.dev Es un dominio de nivel superior registrado recientemente, y en la actualidad está en un periodo inicial implementado con datos destinados a alertar a la gente que lo usa en privado que está a punto de tener un problema. Parte de esto es para devolver sólo la dirección 127.0.53.53, que es lo suficientemente especial como para ser evidente en los archivos de registro de logs y similares, así como también en el bloque 127.0.0.0/8 que está definido como el loopback para IPv4. Es por esta razón que este dominio apunta a la propia máquina. En algunos meses más, es casi seguro que se comience a recibir NXDOMAINs(Non-existent Internet Domain Names Definition) en su lugar.

**Más información en la página oficial de** [ICANN](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2014-08-01-en)

Comment: relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185049/virtualhost-fuerza-https-en-vez-de-http-con-dominio-dev