# VirtualHost fuerza https en vez de http con dominio .dev

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, virtualhost

Tengo creado un *Virtualhost* para un proyecto.

En **`httpd-vhosts.conf`**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
      ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/.../public"
       ServerName don.dev    
</VirtualHost>
```

Y en **`hosts`**:

```
127.0.0.1              don.dev
```

Cuando ingreso en localhost redirecciona sin problemas a `http://localhost/dashboard`

Pero cuando intento ingresar en `http://don.dev` por alguna razón fuerza a `https://don.dev` y tira error de que *"La conexión no es privada"*.

Curiosamente, en Chrome y en Firefox pasa esto. Pero en Internet Explorer no (pudiendo ver la página como debe ser). ¿Alguien sabe porqué?

Lo he realizado siguiendo los tips para Virtualhosts del dashboard de Xampp.

He intentado todo lo que encontre en google, y he probado con diferentes palabras clave sin dar con una solución.

Comment: fijate si no hay un .htaccess que redireccione a https

Comment: Pero si lo hubiera, no me redireccionaría a https en IExplorer tambien?
El .htaccess es el mismo que estaba en el proyecto en ubuntu en otra pc (lo intento traer hacia windows porque la Oracle VirtualBox andaba excesivamente lenta).

Comment: Éste es el .htaccess en el public del proyecto:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    
</IfModule>`
Pero no veo que haya nada que genere el problema..

Comment: fijate si hay algo en el puerto 443, desde un powershell: `New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("localhost",443)`

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que sugieres, pero aqui el resultado..
`New-Object : Excepción al llamar a ".ctor" con los argumentos "2": "No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el
equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión 127.0.0.1:443"
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("localhost",443)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

Comment: hmm ok si ya, .dev es un tld válido (como .com o .org) por eso se fuerza el https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome y Firefox usan filtros para forzar el *https* en top level domains, del tipo `.com`, `.org`, `.net`, etc. mediante una lista https://www.chromium.org/hsts

`.dev` es un [**tld** (Dominio de Nivel Superior)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominio_de_nivel_superior), así que por eso fuerza el *https*. (a este tld se lo fuerza siempre pues parece que es de google)

ref: 
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/7ad1c6b98d17bc442525089ec8997cd81a280546%5E%21/#F0

Prueba cambiarlo a `don.test`, `don.local` o `don.devlocal`

---

Si te interesa puedes leer este artículo en inglés al respecto:
*https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/*

Comment: Eres un genio! no me habia dado cuenta de eso. Ahi lo modifique por .develop y funciona... era eso maestro! :)